# How to join strings in the lines that ended with special string?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text in this format:

> NP00000
>
> Fp
>
> NP00000
>
> Fp
>
> NP00000
>
> Fp
>
> NP00000
>
> Fc
>
> NCMS000
>
> AQ0MS0
>
> Fp
>
> NP00000
>
> Fc
>
> NCMS000
>
> AQ0MS0
>
> SPS00
>
> NCMS000
>
> SPS00
>
> NP00000
>
> Fp
>
> Fx
>
> NP00000
>
> Fp
>
> NP00000
>
> Fp

I want to change that in this format:

> NP00000 
>   Fp
>
> NP00000 
>   Fp
>
> NP00000 
>   Fp
>
> NP00000 
>   Fc 
>   NCMS000 
>   AQ0MS0 
>   Fp
>
> NP00000 
>   Fc 
>   NCMS000 
>   AQ0MS0 
>   SPS00 
>   NCMS000 
>   SPS00 
>   NP00000 
>   Fp
>
> Fx 
>   NP00000 
>   Fp
>
> NP00000 
>   Fp

All the strings join in a line but every line must be end with Fp.

Isn't there anyone to answer my question??

and why i can't add a comment?

@nixda
since I can't add a comment in this topic, I Thank you here. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ replace dialog, select *Extended* and do two replace actions

- Search for: `\r\n`
- Replace with: a single space

This will transform your input text to a single long line

- Search for: `Fp`
- Replace with: `Fp\r\n`

This will replace all Fp strings with a new line break

Comment: First replace shoudl be with " " (a space) instead of nothing to keep the spaces as seperator. Second replace should be with "Fp\r\n". You want to keep the "Fp"  on each line.

Comment: You're right. Overlooked that he wants to keep the `Fp` string

Comment: The second transformation should replace “`Fp `” (with a trailing space) with “`Fp\r\n`”, to avoid leaving the space at the beginning of the next line. And, depending on how paranoid the user is, you should replace “`_Fp_`” (with leading and trailing spaces) with “`_Fp\r\n`”, to avoid matching on a word that ends with “`Fp`”. (I’ve used underscores because SU is handling (backtick)(space) sequences oddly.)